# How do I create a global UnityContainer and access it in all my ViewModels?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, unity-container

My problem is:
I have to resolve the registered type in my `ViewModel` based on what I need at execution time.

Say I have different types of calculation classes inheriting from the same `ICalculation` interface.

On set of the Mean Value property I have to resolve the registered type based on a condition.

To resolve this based on a condition I would need a global container object in my `ViewModel`.

I am using Unity from Microsoft.

Comment: Show the code you made so far.

Comment: Will share my  code tom.it is in my office desktop

Comment: I added some highlighting and improved some grammar.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you don't have to global container at all. You can register your own container with an interface that you create. Then you can use constructor injection and you can get your container wherever.
Like this;

```
    public class SampleModule
        {
            readonly IObjectContainer container;

            public SampleModule(IObjectContainer container)
            {
              this.container = container;
            }
        }
```

Comment: public partial class App : Application
  {
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
      base.OnStartup(e);
      var bootStrapper = new BootStrapper();
      var container = bootStrapper.BootStrap();

      var mainWindow = container.Resolve<MainWindow>();
      mainWindow.Show();
    }
  }

Comment: will that create any problem

Comment: could be problematic at large. Solution that I proposed, recomended by Microsoft itself. You need to think, whats gonna happen if so many thread trying to resolve same object at time. Your container can be lock at any time. Prevent this, you should be create your own object and resolve it base container. Your solution could be solved at first but you are increasing coupling, purpose of using unity decreasing coupling

Comment: Yeah i understand.I have a viewModel which is using two model from the data contract. i have used Fluent Validation for writing rules for the models.Both the model validation is registered under the same DomainModule taking IUnityContainer in the  contructor.I want to resolve it separately and call its validation on respective property setter.Do i have a better approach for this scenario?

Comment: You should be setter injection with strategy pattern approch. Firstly you should be try setter injection with unity. Its very simple in Unity. Just add   [Dependency] attribute to your property. After that you'll get result. Whenever need your property seperatly. You'll get that model (as property in viewmodel) without error (null ref. etc.). With this you can seperate your concern as well. After that you should be check strategy pattern for next level seperation, just for note its just for improving your code, not a must!